# How to position a popup right below an object in CSS

Tags: html, css

I have a `TextBox` in a css within a table. I can't use `position: absolute` in the textbox because I am using table. Is there any other way to position and float the popup (`hint2`) right below the textbox?

My code for css is:

```
/* The hint to Hide and Show */
#hint2 {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    right: 25px;
    top: 65px;
    width: 125px;
    margin-top: -4px;
    border: 1px solid #c93;
    padding: 8px 12px;
    background: #ffc;
    font-size: 10px;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-family: Arial;
}

/* The pointer image is hadded by using another span */
#hint2 .hint2-pointer {
    position: absolute;
    left: 5px;
    top: -10px;
    width: 19px;
    height: 10px;
    background: url(images/pointer.gif) left top no-repeat;
}
```

My textbox HTML is:

```
<input style="background: url(images/find.png) center left no-repeat; padding-left: 20px; padding-top: 2px; padding-bottom: 2px; padding-right: 4px; font-family: Arial, Verdana; color: #EB620E" type="text" id="TextBox1" size="10" />
```

I am currently using `position: absolute` in the popup but that only makes it relative to the page. When I resize the window the popup changes location.

Originally it looks like this:
[image]

Here is the HTML code:

```
<td style="width:20%" align="right"> <!-- 55% -->
    <table width="100%" class="right">
        <tr>
            <td style="vertical-align:middle; white-space:nowrap;" class="auto-style2 subNavOrg">
                <a href="default.aspx">HOME</a>
                &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                <a href="https://login.myonline.com/">My ONLINE</a>
                &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                <a href="patient_information.aspx">INFORMATION</a>
                <br />
                <input style="position: relative; background: url(images/find.png) center left no-repeat; padding-left: 20px; padding-top: 2px; padding-bottom: 2px; padding-right: 4px; font-family: Arial, Verdana; color: #EB620E" type="text" id="TextBox1" size="10" />
                <span id="hint2">Search query is empty<span class="hint2-pointer">&nbsp;</span></span>
                <input id="Button1" type="button" value="Search" class="locButton" />
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</td>
```

Comment: Could you provide this code on a http://jsfiddle.net or http://jsbin.com paste, so that we can test it ourselves? Also please include the other relevant HTML on here, such as the `<table>` you mentioned in your question.

Comment: I added the HTML code for preview. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try putting an `inline-block` element around the two elements you're trying to position underneath eachother:

```
<table width="100%" class="right">
    <tr>
        <td style="vertical-align:middle; white-space:nowrap;" class="auto-style2 subNavOrg">
            <a href="default.aspx">HOME</a>
            &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
            <a href="https://login.myonline.com/">My ONLINE</a>
            &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
            <a href="patient_information.aspx">INFORMATION</a>
            <br />
            <span class="ib">
                <input style="position: relative; background: url(images/find.png) center left no-repeat; padding-left: 20px; padding-top: 2px; padding-bottom: 2px; padding-right: 4px; font-family: Arial, Verdana; color: #EB620E" type="text" id="TextBox1" size="10" />
                <br />
                <span id="hint2">Search query is empty<span class="hint2-pointer">&nbsp;</span></span>
            </span>
            <input id="Button1" type="button" value="Search" class="locButton" />
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

and then use the following CSS code:

```
.ib {
  display:inline-block;
  vertical-align:top;
}
```

If you insist on using inline styles, you can also replace `class="ib"` with `style="display:inline-block;vertical-align:top;"`, but usually it is better to seperate styling from content, for making maintenance a lot easier.

[**Here's a demo**](http://jsbin.com/EGIYivUb/1/) of what this would look like.

Comment: Should I keep the position for hint2 to `relative`? I made the edit but what happens is, when the span is displayed the contents for rest of the page gets pushed by a few pixels.

Comment: No, you don't need that anymore. You can also edit the code yourself to see what it does, at http://jsbin.com/EGIYivUb/1/edit (or http://jsbin.com/EGIYivUb/2/edit if you want the relative positioning removed).